# makefile:437: recipe for target 'general/socketstream.o' failed

Tags: mingw

I am installing the Finite Element Discretization Library called MFEM following instructions at https://mfem.org/building/

When I enter command 'make serial -j' in the right folder('mfem-4.3' in my case), I got the error below.

I am using Windows 10 and Git Bash.

```
$ make serial -j
D:/MinGW/bin/make -f makefile config MFEM_USE_MPI=NO MFEM_DEBUG=NO \

make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/mfem/mfem-4.3'
D:/MinGW/bin/make -C config all
make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/mfem/mfem-4.3/config'
make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/mfem/mfem-4.3/config'

Build destination: <source> [D:/mfem/mfem-4.3]

make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/mfem/mfem-4.3'
D:/MinGW/bin/make
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/mfem/mfem-4.3'
g++   -O3 -std=c++11   -c general/socketstream.cpp -o general/socketstream.o
makefile:437: recipe for target 'general/socketstream.o' failed
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -c general/socketstream.cpp -o general/socketstream.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): ϵͳ▒Ҳ▒▒▒ָ▒▒▒▒▒ļ▒▒▒
make[1]: *** [general/socketstream.o] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/mfem/mfem-4.3'
makefile:478: recipe for target 'serial' failed
make: *** [serial] Error 2
```

how can I fix this?

And the following are contents in Makefile

row number 435-437:

```
# Rules for compiling all source files.
$(OBJECT_FILES): $(BLD)%.o: $(SRC)%.cpp $(CONFIG_MK)
    $(MFEM_CXX) $(MFEM_BUILD_FLAGS) -c $(<) -o $(@)
```

row number 477-480

```
serial parallel debug pdebug:
    $(MAKE) -f $(THIS_MK) config MFEM_USE_MPI=$(M_MPI) MFEM_DEBUG=$(M_DBG) \
       $(MAKEOVERRIDES_SAVE)
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEOVERRIDES_SAVE)
```